# How do I validate the post request from ajax? I have invalid ajax data is writing to GAE Data store,

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery

In my webapp I take data from a js function and post it to a special handler via ajax post. Once I get the data, I write it to my db.

My problem is I have double data for each ajax post (ajax is firing twice and I need to figure out why, but this is another issue).

I'm trying to catch these double firings, as of now I know the first set is null values, every piece of data I grab from the self.request.get(someVar) is null from the first ajax post firing..

I tried doing

```
if not someVar:
    #data is valid, write to db...
```

but although these values are null, they're still getting past my if functions and my db is writing in null values... I'm thinking of making them strings and making sure their length is greater than 0 maybe...

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Could you please post the code you are referring to? By just trying a POST to a handler that does self.request.get(), the "if not" syntax seems to work as expected on the SDK. I suspect there is something else going on.

Comment: I found my error. it appears there's nothing wrong with "if not" syntax, but somewhere else I was screwing things up and I narrowed it down to this :(

Answer (score 2):

I found my error. it appears there's nothing wrong with "if not" syntax, but somewhere else in my code I was screwing things up and I mistakenly narrowed it down to this :(